# Can you download apps from Google play onto an Android Studio AVD (Android Virtual Device)?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, google-play

I was wondering- can you download apps from google play onto an Android Studio AVD (Android Virtual Device)? If you can, how do you do that? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the [Genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/) emulator. It allows to install apps from the store without a problem and it's really quick in comparison with standard emulator.

Other way to install apps from Google Play is to extract the APK and install the app in the emulator via `adb`:

```
adb install <path>/Twitter.apk
```

You can download the APK directly from the [web](http://www.apkmirror.com) or via an [app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ext.ui&hl=en).

Comment: Is Genymotion free?

Comment: Yes, it is free for personal use. Here is the pricing information: https://www.genymotion.com/pricing-and-licensing/

Comment: To install an APK file in an Android Studio AVD, you just have to drag-n-drop the file onto a running emulator window ([source](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator#installadd)). Tested in Android Studio 3.3.1.